# How much of Kimi no Iru Machi is adapted?

Tags: kimi-no-iru-machi

I want to know how much of the *Kimi no Iru Machi* anime is adapted from the manga, and whether or not the anime skipped any content from it.

Comment: Are you referring to Tatsunoko OVA, Gonzo TV anime, or both?

Comment: @кяαzєя I referred to what I was referring in the second sentence `...and whether or not the anime skipped...`

Comment: Both are considered 'anime', if you didn't know. One is released directly to home video, while the other is broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anime series skipped the Hiroshima part and goes straight to the Tokyo part where Haruto was chasing after the disappearing Eba. It ended with Haruto breaking up with Asuka and going back with Yuzuki. Haruto moved out from his sister's place to live together with Yuzuki.

The OVA animated the Hiroshima part of the story and ended with Yuzuki moving back to Tokyo, thus the OVA should be watched before the serial. Since the OVA is only 2 episodes long it omitted many small detail.

There is also a gap between the OVA and the serial in that it skipped Eba breaking up with Haruto. The serial started with they already breaking up.